# Is to possible to have office documents opened in LibreOffice while using RStudio on modern Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, libreoffice, rstudio, markdown

I use Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS with installed R and RStudio to build bookdown books and documents.

Previously I used these applications in 16.04 LTS.
Building/knitting book or single RMarkdown document to odt/docx ended here by showing the document in LibreOffice Writer.

In 18.04 LTS the behavior is changed.
Knitting document or book to odt/docx does not show the document in LibreOffice.

If I launch RStudio from the terminal and hit *Knit* or *Build Book* it shows the following output:

> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/javaldx: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
> /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libreglo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

---

The `libreglo.so` is really in place:

```
$ dpkg -S libreglo.so
uno-libs3: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libreglo.so
```

Libreoffice Java binding is in place

```
$ dpkg -l libreoffice-java-common | tail -n1
ii  libreoffice-java-common 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 all          office productivity suite -- arch-independent Java support files

$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Enabling/disabling Java in `loffice`, *Tools* → *Options*, LibreOffice, *Advanced*, *[ ] Use a Java runtime environment* does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem we need to add the following line with LD_LIBRARY_PATH at the end of `~/.profile` and to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/libreoffice/program:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

and to `rstudio.desktop` launcher:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cp /usr/share/applications/rstudio.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
sed -i "s|/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio|env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libreoffice/program /usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio|"  ~/.local/share/applications/rstudio.desktop
```

---

Note: this method is also applicable to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 20.10.

Comment: /usr/lib is one of the places the dynamic linker looks at for libs. Would be better to find out why it's not in the search path and fix that.